# Trying to scrape a website containing Japanese characters with lxml, but all characters are getting matched.

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, unicode, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrape [this webpage](http://www013.upp.so-net.ne.jp/santai/santai.htm) which contains many kanji, each associated with a single linked image. I'm trying this so far, where `character` represents a single kanji:

```
kanji_page = requests.get('http://www013.upp.so-net.ne.jp/santai/santai.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(kanji_page.content) # now contains the whole HTML page  
page_url = tree.xpath('//a[contains(text(), '+character+')]/@href')
return page_url # returns a list of image URLs
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me the href URL of *every single character on the page*, not just the one that matches. So say, I enter 火, I'd like to return *just* the URL for that (`/jpg/0075.jpg`). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how are you passing the `character`? Could you share a complete working example?

Comment: Sure thing. I'm testing it as a local function now, but eventually it would take the character from a web comment.

     `def ja_calligraphy_search(character):`

         `word = input("Enter the input: ")`

        `results = ja_calligraphy_search(word)`

        `print(results)`



Then the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the `"` in the xpath expression:

change it to:

```
'//a[contains(text(), "'+character+'")]/@href'
```

Comment: Gosh, I'm such an idiot and a Python noob. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad to help, please remember to accept if it helped!